# How is the class label applied in the softmax function?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, softmax

Im reading this paper: [Uncertainty in Deep Learning](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/thesis/thesis.pdf) and in it (page4), the *softmax loss* is defined as

\begin{align*}
E(X,Y) = -\frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{n=1} \log(\hat{p}_{n,c_n}),
\end{align*}

where $c_n \in \{1,...,D\}$ is the class label for input $n$, and

$\hat{p}_{nd} = \exp(\hat{y}_{nd})/(\sum_{d'} \exp(\hat{y}_{nd'})$ is the element-wise softmax-function applied to model prediction vector $\hat{y}$.

Where does the class label $d$ actually show up in the softmax calculation? I.e. what does $\hat{y}_{nd}$ or $\hat{p}_{n,c_n}$ respectively shall mean?

Thanks

Comment: The $y_i$ is either 0 or 1.

Comment: yes Sir, thats correct for (binary) classification

Comment: There are $D$ classes. $\hat{y}_{nd}$ for $d \in \{1,\dots,D\}$ are the probabilities for the $n$th sampling unit, and $\hat{y}_{n,c_n}$ is the largest probability (of the $D$ probabilities).

Comment: Thanks @papgeo for your answer. Your explaination of $\hat{y}_{nd}$ makes sense, thank you! And you mean $\hat{p}_{n,c_n}$ to be the largest probability?

Comment: If you formulate those insights into an answer, Im willing to accept that.

Comment: @papgeo I don’t follow what you mean by the largest probability.

Comment: @Dave Apologies, that's not what it is.

Comment: @MJimitater Apologies, that's not what it is.

Comment: @Dave oh yes, thanks for pointing that one out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given $N$ input-output pairs: $\{(\textbf{x}_1,y_1),\dots,(\textbf{x}_N,y_N)\}$. The $\textbf{x}$'s are input vectors, also known as covariates or predictors, and the $y$'s are the labels. The problem here is to learn how to predict a class label given the vector of inputs $\textbf{x}$.

$\hat{y}_{nd}$ is what brings the $\textbf{x}$'s into the computations. It is also known as the linear predictor and it is given by $\hat{y}_{nd} = \beta_{0d} + \beta_{1d} x_{1n} + \dots + \beta_{pd} x_{pn}$, where the $\beta$'s are regression coefficients (to be estimated) and $x_{1n}, \dots, x_{pn}$ are the elements of the input vector $\textbf{x}_n$.

$\hat{p}_{n,c_n}$ is the probability of the class that sampling unit $n$ belongs to.